# syntax error on concatenating variables to the string

Tags: vue.js

Here i'm doing the concatination while setting the state.but it's giving the syntax error.i'm obviously a newbie in vue js world.

```
export default{
  data: function(){
    return{
      http_options:{
              headers:{
                '"Authorization": "Basic '+ this.$store.state.authorization + '"'
              }
             },
```

Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (11:42)

```
 http_options:{
                headers:{
                '"Authorization": "Basic '+ this.$store.state.authorization + '"'
                                          ^
                }
              }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ES6 Template Strings

```
headers:{
  "Authorization": `Basic ${this.$store.state.authorization}`                     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a mismatch of `'` and `"`. Just use:

```
 headers:{
    Authorization: "Basic "+ this.$store.state.authorization
 }
```

of if you need the `'` around the `this.$store.state.authorization` (which I HIGHLY doubt if you're doing [basic auth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization#Examples)) then

```
 headers:{
    Authorization: "Basic '"+ this.$store.state.authorization + "'"
 }
```